# Why is padding/margin smaller on Firefox than Safari even with reset css?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am developing a website at the moment and even though I have a reset css included in my css, Firefox and Safari are showing two different results.

Here is what they look like:

#### Safari & Chrome:

[image]

#### Firefox:

[image]

As you can see, both Safari and Chrome display as they should. Firefox, on the other hand does not. There is more padding/margin at the top and it overflows at the bottom.

How would I get Firefox to show the same as Safari and Chrome?

Note: I am also using the [Meyer Web reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

#### SASS:

```
@import variables.sass
$postWidth: 200px
#content
  min-height: calc(100% - 400px)
  .blog-post
    display: flex
    border-bottom: 1px solid $blue
    .day
      width: #{$postWidth}
    .post
      width: calc(100% - #{$postWidth})
```

#### CSS:

```
#content .blog-post {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2da2dc
}

#content .blog-post .day {
    width: 200px
}

#content .blog-post .post {
    width: calc(100% - 200px)
}
```

Comment: try using Normalize CSS instead of Reset. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/